# Why does "sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0" run only one time?

Tags: 14.04, gps

I do not know why `sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0` runs only one time.

I have the U-blox EVK-M8T which can read the NMEA messages through the Ubuntu terminal window. When I have set up, and type the command `sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0`, it show me the NMEA meassages, such as:

```
$GLGSV,3,3,09,87,06,340,*52
$GNGLL,,,,,140236.00,V,N*56
$GNZDA,140236.00,10,03,2017,00,00*7C
$GNRMC,140236.85,V,,,,,,,100317,,,N*68
$GNVTG,,,,,,,,,N*2E
$GNGGA,140236.85,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*77
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*2E
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*2E
$GPGSV,3,1,12,10,76,330,52,11,03,322,44,12,23,100,47,14,32,270,44*7E
$GPGSV,3,2,12,15,10,077,,18,70,123,46,20,02,130,47,21,22,189,47*73
$GPGSV,3,3,12,24,40,050,49,25,16,142,39,31,13,211,48,32,52,288,50*72
$GLGSV,3,1,09,69,26,096,28,70,62,024,37,71,30,315,29,73,37,171,36*6A
$GLGSV,3,2,09,79,20,030,,80,64,095,31,85,09,235,27,86,20,287,33*62
$GNGLL,,,,,140236.85,V,N*5B
$GNZDA,140236.85,10,03,2017,00,00*71
```

but suddenly, it stopped running without touching anything. I do not know why, and I tried to run again but it did not run. Until I mechanically unplugged the USB cable and connected it again, then it worked.

This happened again, again and again...

I also tried to use: stty -F /dev/ttyACM0  . But the message below shows empty information:

```
speed 57600 baud; line = 0;
intr = <undef>; quit = <undef>; erase = <undef>; kill = <undef>; eof = ^A; start = <undef>; stop = <undef>; susp = <undef>; rprnt = <undef>; werase = <undef>; lnext = <undef>; discard = <undef>;
min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl ixoff ixany -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

What are these?

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Most obvious answer: the tty is not sending any signals. Use the `stty` command to read tty's. (for instance `stty -F ${PortName}  ${SerialSpeed}  raw -clocal -echo icrnl`).

Comment: @Rinzwind : could you please give me more detail a little bit? what is ${PortName} ${SerialSpeed}?

Comment: `/dev/ttyACM0` for the portname and `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0` will show the speed.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I tried that way but it give me empty messages, you could see in "my question" area , i just added more about the empty messages.